# How do i point two fields to use the same value in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I have this Object below, and as you can see, "valid" and "pending" are using the same value, is there a way to put this in one line rather than duplicating "custom-info" ?

```
  Map = {
    'failed': 'custom-error',
    'pending': 'custom-info',
    'valid': 'custom-info'
  };
```

Comment: `valid: this.pending` should do the trick though it barely saves you anything. You will have to define `valid` anyhow.

Comment: @somethinghere no that doesnt seem to work for soem reason

Comment: Ah indeed it doesn't. I could have sworn I had done it before and it worked, but true, that doesn't work. Ah well, thats why I posted it as a comment :) The answers below could solve your problem, tbh, but I think _in this particular case_ you might be overcomplicating something that works perfectly fine as is. (Also, you can remove the `'` around your keys - it reads more clearly - and unless you are using characters you are not allowed to use in variables names, they are not necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign string value to constant and set property value using constant.

```
const CUSTOMER_INFO = 'custom-info';
Map = {
    'failed': 'custom-error',
    'pending': CUSTOMER_INFO,
    'valid': CUSTOMER_INFO
  };
```

This helps only if setting property value many times and used somewhere else also otherwise setting string value in object is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a shorthand, but remember that strings, being primitives, are passed as copies, and this may not behave as you need.

```
Enum = {
  'error': 'custom-error',
  'info': 'custom-info'
};

Map = {
  'failed': Enum.error,
  'pending': Enum.info,
  'valid': Enum.info
};
```

If you need actual references to objects, I suggest:

```
Enum = function(type) {
  var keys = {
      error : { text: "custom-error" },
      info : { text: "custom-info" }
  };

  return keys[type];
};


Map = {
  'failed': Enum('error'),
  'pending': Enum('info'),
  'valid': Enum('info')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map = {
  'failed': 'custom-error'
};
Map.pending = Map.valid = 'custom-info';
```